# How to force Sqlalchemy to point to a schema different from the default schema for a connection string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, python-oracledb

I have an oracle database connection with just a read access. When I connect to the database using collection string

```
engine = create_engine(f"oracle+oracledb://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_URL{DB_PORT}/{DB_SID}")
```

This connect successful but the default database schema to this connect/SID point to **PD_READONLY** which has empty tables. The Schema with the right data/tables is **PD_FULL_ACCESS**.

Using any database visualizer, I can query the data in the **PD_FULL_ACCESS** using return the expected data.

```
SELECT date_created, date_modified from PD_FULL_ACCESS.department;
```

```
SELECT date_created, date_modified from department;
```

return an error `[Code: 942, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00942: table or view does not exist [Script position: 102 - 105]` which is valid because there is no such table in the default **PD_READONLY**.

My SQL schema is as follows:

```
class Department:
    __tablename__ = "department"
    __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__ = "sa"

    id: float = field(
        init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False), primary_key=True)}
    )
    label: str = field(metadata={"sa": Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)})
    active: str = field(
        metadata={"sa": Column(CHAR(1), nullable=False, server_default=text("'Y' "))}
    )
```

How can I force Sqlalchemy to point all queries e.g `session.query(Department).all()` to **PD_FULL_ACCESS** instead of the default **PD_READONLY**

I have tried specifying the **schema/service_name** in the connect string as:

**DB_SERVICE_NAME="PD_READONLY"**

```
engine = create_engine(
    f"oracle+oracledb://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_URL}:{DB_PORT}/?service_name={DB_SERVICE_NAME}")
```

This gives the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError) DPY-4027: no configuration directory to search for tnsnames.ora
```

I also tried:

```
engine = create_engine(f"oracle+oracledb://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_URL}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_SERVICE_NAME}")
```

which give the error

```
SID "None" is not registered with the listener at host
```

> Both attempt above looks like there need to be a tnslister tweak on the database level. A**ny solution on the database level is not feasible in this case** as the database is legacy application with many dependency and it cannot be changed/modified because of this case.

On the query level, I tried a naïve approach to add the schema to the query as:

```
db.query("PD_FULL_ACCESS.Department").all()
```

got the error:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Textual column expression 'PD_FULL_ACCESS.Department' should be explicitly declared with text('PD_FULL_ACCESS.Department'), or use column('PD_FULL_ACCESS.Department') for more specificity
```

The project is setup to use ORM rather than plan sql queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `schema_translation_map` when you create the engine. For example, if the model does not contain a specific schema

```py
class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = "department"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
```

and we just do

```
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

then queries like

```py
qry = select(Department)
```

will run against the default schema for the current user. However, if we do

```py
engine = create_engine(
    connection_url,
    execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {None: "PD_FULL_ACCESS"}},
)
```

then SQLAlchemy will build SQL statements that target the specified schema.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works for my case

Answer (score 0):

In your connect string you are missing the `=` sign. You need something like this:

```
f"oracle+oracledb://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_URL}:{DB_PORT}/?service_name={DB_SERVICE_NAME}"
```

The second issue has the solution in the error message itself. Did you try that?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The `=` here is an omission. It does not work with it too. The second solution is tending toward using raw queries which is not an option in this case.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the explanation. Good thing someone with more SQLAlchemy experience responded, too!